# Webpack: how to import a custom javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to import a custom js file with webpack but without success.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    'main' : './src/app.js',
    'custom': './src/custom.js'
  }, 
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      }
    ]
  },
    optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "main.css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

app.js

```
import './custom.js';
```

in custom.js there is only some custom js code.

```
!function(e){var o=!1;if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&(define(e),o=!0),"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=e(),o=!0),!o){var t=window.Cookies,n=window.Cookies=e();n.noConflict=function(){return window.Cookies=t,n}}}(function(){function k(){for(var e=0,o={};e<arguments.length;e++){var t=arguments[e];for(var n in t)o[n]=t[n]}return o}return function e(p){function f(e,o,t){var n;if("undefined"!=typeof document){if(1<arguments.length){if("number"==typeof(t=k({path:"/"},f.defaults,t)).expires){var i=new Date;i.setMilliseconds(i.getMilliseconds()+864e5*t.expires),t.expires=i}t.expires=t.expires?t.expires.toUTCString():"";try{n=JSON.stringify(o),/^[\{\[]/.test(n)&&(o=n)}catch(e){}o=p.write?p.write(o,e):encodeURIComponent(String(o)).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|3A|3C|3E|3D|2F|3F|40|5B|5D|5E|60|7B|7D|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent),e=(e=(e=encodeURIComponent(String(e))).replace(/%(23|24|26|2B|5E|60|7C)/g,decodeURIComponent)).replace(/[\(\)]/g,escape);var c="";for(var a in t)t[a]&&(c+="; "+a,!0!==t[a]&&(c+="="+t[a]));return document.cookie=e+"="+o+c}e||(n={});for(var r=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],s=/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g,d=0;d<r.length;d++){var l=r[d].split("="),m=l.slice(1).join("=");this.json||'"'!==m.charAt(0)||(m=m.slice(1,-1));try{var u=l[0].replace(s,decodeURIComponent);if(m=p.read?p.read(m,u):p(m,u)||m.replace(s,decodeURIComponent),this.json)try{m=JSON.parse(m)}catch(e){}if(e===u){n=m;break}e||(n[u]=m)}catch(e){}}return n}}return(f.set=f).get=function(e){return f.call(f,e)},f.getJSON=function(){return f.apply({json:!0},[].slice.call(arguments))},f.defaults={},f.remove=function(e,o){f(e,"",k(o,{expires:-1}))},f.withConverter=e,f}(function(){})}),window["gdpr-cookie-notice-templates"]={},window["gdpr-cookie-notice-templates"]["bar.html"]='<div class="gdpr-cookie-notice"><div class="content">\n <p style="color:white;"><b>Informativa</b></p>\n  <p class="gdpr-cookie-notice-description">{description}</p>\n  <nav class="gdpr-cookie-notice-nav text-center">\n   <a href="#" class="gdpr-cookie-notice-nav-item gdpr-cookie-notice-nav-item-accept gdpr-cookie-notice-nav-item-btn">{accept}</a>\n  </nav>\n</div></div>\n',window["gdpr-cookie-notice-templates"]["category.html"]='<li class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie">\n  <div class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie-row">\n    <h3 class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie-title">{title}</h3>\n    <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr-cookie-notice-{prefix}" checked="checked" id="gdpr-cookie-notice-{prefix}" class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie-input">\n    <label class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie-input-switch" for="gdpr-cookie-notice-{prefix}"></label>\n  </div>\n  <p class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookie-info">{desc}</p>\n</li>\n',window["gdpr-cookie-notice-templates"]["modal.html"]='<div class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal">\n  <div class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-content">\n    <div class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-header">\n      <h2 class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-title">{settings}</h2>\n      <button type="button" class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-close"></button>\n    </div>\n    <ul class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-cookies"></ul>\n    <div class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer">\n      <a href="#" class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer-item gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer-item-statement">{statement}</a>\n      <a href="#" class="gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer-item gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer-item-save gdpr-cookie-notice-modal-footer-item-btn"><span>{save}</span></a>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n';var gdprCookieNoticeLocales={};function gdprCookieNotice(c){var n="gdprcookienotice",a="gdpr-cookie-notice",r=window[a+"-templates"],i=Cookies.noConflict(),s=!1,d=!1,l=!1,m=["performance","analytics","marketing"];c.locale||(c.locale="en"),c.timeout||(c.timeout=500),c.domain||(c.domain=null),c.expiration||(c.expiration=30),void 0===gdprCookieNoticeLocales[c.locale]&&(c.locale="en");var u=i.getJSON(n),p=new CustomEvent("gdprCookiesEnabled",{detail:u});function f(e){for(var o=!1,t=0;t<m.length;t++)if(c[m[t]]&&!e[m[t]])for(var n=0;n<c[m[t]].length;n++)i.remove(c[m[t]][n]),o=!0;o?g():document.documentElement.classList.remove(a+"-loaded")}function k(e){var o={date:new Date,necessary:!0,performance:!0,analytics:!0,marketing:!0};if(e)for(var t=0;t<m.length;t++)o[m[t]]=document.getElementById(a+"-cookie_"+m[t]).checked;i.set(n,o,{expires:c.expiration,domain:c.domain}),f(o),p=new CustomEvent("gdprCookiesEnabled",{detail:o}),document.dispatchEvent(p)}function e(){if(d)return!1;var e,o,t=v("bar.html");document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",t),e=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-nav-item-settings")[0],o=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-nav-item-accept")[0],e.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault(),h()}),o.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault(),k()}),d=!0}function g(){e(),setTimeout(function(){document.documentElement.classList.add(a+"-loaded")},c.timeout)}function v(e,t){var o=r[e],n=gdprCookieNoticeLocales[c.locale];if(t?t+="_":t="",!("string"==typeof o&&n instanceof Object))return!1;for(var i in n)return o.replace(/({([^}]+)})/g,function(e){var o=e.replace(/{/,"").replace(/}/,"");return"prefix"==o?t.slice(0,-1):n[o]?n[o]:n[t+o]?n[t+o]:e})}function o(){if(s)return!1;var e=v("modal.html");document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",e);var o=document.querySelector("."+a+"-modal-cookies");o.innerHTML+=v("category.html","cookie_essential");var t=document.querySelector("."+a+"-modal-cookie-input"),n=document.querySelector("."+a+"-modal-cookie-input-switch");n.innerHTML=gdprCookieNoticeLocales[c.locale].always_on,n.classList.add(a+"-modal-cookie-state"),n.classList.remove(a+"-modal-cookie-input-switch"),t.remove(),c.performance&&(o.innerHTML+=v("category.html","cookie_performance")),c.analytics&&(o.innerHTML+=v("category.html","cookie_analytics")),c.marketing&&(o.innerHTML+=v("category.html","cookie_marketing")),function(){var e=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-modal-close")[0],o=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-modal-footer-item-statement")[0],t=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-modal-cookie-title"),n=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-modal-footer-item-save")[0];e.addEventListener("click",function(){return document.documentElement.classList.remove(a+"-show-modal"),!1}),o.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault(),window.location.href=c.statement});for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)t[i].addEventListener("click",function(){return this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle("open"),!1});n.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault(),n.classList.add("saved"),setTimeout(function(){n.classList.remove("saved")},1e3),k(!0)})}(),u&&(document.getElementById(a+"-cookie_performance").checked=u.performance,document.getElementById(a+"-cookie_analytics").checked=u.analytics,document.getElementById(a+"-cookie_marketing").checked=u.marketing),s=!0}function h(){o(),document.documentElement.classList.add(a+"-show-modal")}u?(f(u),document.dispatchEvent(p)):(g(),c.implicit&&window.addEventListener("scroll",function e(){var o,t,n,i,c;o=window.innerHeight||(document.documentElement||document.body).clientHeight,c=document,t=Math.max(c.body.scrollHeight,c.documentElement.scrollHeight,c.body.offsetHeight,c.documentElement.offsetHeight,c.body.clientHeight,c.documentElement.clientHeight),n=window.pageYOffset||(document.documentElement||document.body.parentNode||document.body).scrollTop,i=t-o,10<Math.floor(n/i*100)&&!l&&(l=!0)&&(k(),window.removeEventListener("click",e))}));var t=document.querySelectorAll("."+a+"-settings-button");if(t)for(var y=0;y<t.length;y++)t[y].addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefault(),h()})}gdprCookieNoticeLocales.en={description:"We use cookies to offer you a better browsing experience, personalise content and ads, to provide social media features and to analyse our traffic. Read about how we use cookies and how you can control them by clicking <a href='#' class='gdpr-cookie-notice-nav-item-settings'>Cookie Settings</a>. You consent to our cookies if you continue to use this website.",settings:"Cookie settings",accept:"Accept cookies",statement:"Our cookie statement",save:"Save settings",always_on:"Always on",cookie_essential_title:"Essential website cookies",cookie_essential_desc:"Necessary cookies help make a website usable by enabling basic functions like page navigation and access to secure areas of the website. The website cannot function properly without these cookies.",cookie_performance_title:"Performance cookies",cookie_performance_desc:"These cookies are used to enhance the performance and functionality of our websites but are non-essential to their use. For example it stores your preferred language or the region that you are in.",cookie_analytics_title:"Analytics cookies",cookie_analytics_desc:"We use analytics cookies to help us measure how users interact with website content, which helps us customize our websites and application for you in order to enhance your experience.",cookie_marketing_title:"Marketing cookies",cookie_marketing_desc:"These cookies are used to make advertising messages more relevant to you and your interests. The intention is to display ads that are relevant and engaging for the individual user and thereby more valuable for publishers and third party advertisers."};gdprCookieNoticeLocales.it={description:"Utilizziamo i cookie di prima e di terza parte per offire una migliore esperienza di navigazione, personalizzare il contenuto e le pubblicità, fornire funzionalità relative ai social media e per analizzare il traffico sul sito. Leggi la <a href='https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/xxxx/cookie-policy' target='_blank'>Cookie Policy</a> <a href='#' class='gdpr-cookie-notice-nav-item-settings'></a> per maggiori informazioni su come utilizziamo i cookie e come puoi gestirne le impostazioni. Continuando a utilizzare il sito, acconsenti all'utilizzo dei cookie.",settings:"Impostazioni dei cookie",accept:"Accetta",statement:"Cookie Policy",save:"Salva impostazioni",always_on:"Sempre attivi",cookie_essential_title:"Cookie essenziali",cookie_essential_desc:"",cookie_performance_title:"Performance cookies",cookie_performance_desc:"",cookie_analytics_title:"Analytics cookies",cookie_analytics_desc:"",cookie_marketing_title:"Marketing cookies",cookie_marketing_desc:""};
```

When I do `npm run build` the custom.js file is empty.
I expected it contains my custom js code instead.

Why is it empty?

Comment: Can you show what's within `custom.js`?

Comment: @yousoumar the question now include also the custom js content